# How do you obtain the body of a function?

Tags: python

I would need to separate the signature from the body of a function in Python, i.e. :

```
def mult(a, b):
    "Multiplication"
    if a or b is None:
       # border case
       return None
    else:
       return a * b
```

(the function is there for demonstration only).

I know that `inspect.getsourcelines(mult)` will get me the full code, but I would like to have only the body, i.e. less the signature and the docstring:

```
if a or b is None:
   # border case
   return None
else:
   return a * b
```

Is there an elegant way to obtain that, ideally using Python3 built-in parsing tools, rather than string manipulation?

Comment: Signature may span multiple lines, though

Comment: The question of the docstring is "elegantly" solved (@IMCoins), so it seems that the most important question left is how to determine the number of lines of the signature? It is correct that a signature may span multiple lines, but also a signature may be followed by a comment on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't know any function that does this, here is a homemade function that should work.
I don't have time for more in-depth use-cases. So i'll leave my incomplete answer here.

```
def get_body(func):
    """ Using the magic method __doc__, we KNOW the size of the docstring.
        We then, just substract this from the total length of the function
    """
    try:
        lines_to_skip = len(func.__doc__.split('\n'))
    except AttributeError:
        lines_to_skip = 0

    lines = getsourcelines(func)[0]

    return ''.join( lines[lines_to_skip+1:] )

def ex_0(a, b):
    """ Please !
        Don't

    Show
This
    """
    if a or b is None:
       # border case
       return None
    else:
       return a * b

def ex_1(a, b):
    ''' Please !Don'tShowThis'''
    if a or b is None:
       # border case
       return None
    else:
       return a * b

def ex_2(a, b):
    if a or b is None:
       # border case
       return None
    else:
       return a * b

def ex_3(bullshit, hello):
    pass

get_body(ex_0)
    # if a or b is None:
    #    # border case
    #    return None
    # else:
    #    return a * b

get_body(ex_1)
    # if a or b is None:
    #    # border case
    #    return None
    # else:
    #    return a * b

get_body(ex_2)
    # if a or b is None:
    #    # border case
    #    return None
    # else:
    #    return a * b

get_body(ex_3)
    # pass
```

Comment: Docstrings can also be created using triple single quotes `'''`. Not to mention the fact that they can be broken into multiple lines

Comment: @abdusco Let me edit with the unittest. The no docstring part is handled with the except AttributeError

Comment: The solution breaks when the signature is split into multiple lines. Or if there're blank lines before the docstring starts

Answer (score 1):

you can use this also

```
i = inspect.getsource(fun_name).index('\n')
j = inspect.getsource(fun_name).rindex(':',0,i)

print(inspect.getsource(fun_name)[j+1:])
```

Comment: What happens when the signature includes type annotations `def func(param: int):`

Comment: why we pass parameters like this, can you give me some example

Comment: check the new one solution

Comment: What happens when there's `with open(file) as f:` or `if expression:` or `for expression:` blocks?

Comment: It will work because function defination starts after first new line character and I get the index of right most ':'  after that it will print the body which is actually the definition and if their is any lambda function or any function or for and if in first line then we can also check the condition of check the word in string if present then get the index of that word and print all the string after that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196457/discussion-between-shubham-and-abdusco).

Answer (score 0):

If you know your code will always have a non-empty docstring like a above, You can do this with the built in inspect library.

The below snippet should get you acquainted with how to see the source code body of a function.

```py
def hello_world():
   """Python port of original Fortran code"""
   print("hello_world")

import inspect
source = inspect.getsource(hello_world)
doc = hello_world.__doc__
code = source.split(doc)
body = code[1]
print(body)
```

**EDIT:**

I thought about this some more, you can first remove the defintion line and then strip out the docstring if it exists:

```py
def hello_world():
   """Python port of original Fortran code"""
   print("hello_world")

import inspect
source = inspect.getsource(hello_world)
doc = hello_world.__doc__
code = source.split(':',1)
body= code[1].replace(doc, "")
body = body.replace('""""""',"")  
print(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the inspiring answers! I tried to take this further and I found a solution that uses Python's ast facilities.

```
import inspect, ast
from astunparse import unparse
def mult(a,
    b): # comment
    """
    This is a 'doctstring', "hello"
    """
    if not a is None or b is None:
        # border case
        return None
    else:
        return a * b


def get_body(f, doc_string=False):
    """
    Get the body text of a function, i.e. without the signature.
    NOTE: Comments are stripped.
    """
    COMMENT_START = ("'", '"')
    code = inspect.getsource(mult)
    # print("Function's code:\n", code)
    module_tree = ast.parse(code) # this creates a module
    # print("Dump:\n", ast.dump(module_tree))
    # the first element of the module is evidently the function:
    function_body = module_tree.body[0].body
    # strip the code lines to remove the additional lines:
    lines = [unparse(code_line).strip() for code_line in function_body]
    # for i, line in enumerate(lines): print("%s: %s" % (i, line.strip()))
    # in principle the notion of body contains the docstring:
    if not doc_string:
        lines = (line for line in lines if not line.startswith(COMMENT_START))
    return '\n'.join(lines).strip()


s =get_body(mult)
print("---------")
print(s)
```

Here is the result:

```
$ python3 function_body.py
---------
if ((not (a is None)) or (b is None)):
    return None
else:
    return (a * b)
```

You can choose if you want the docstring or not. The downside of this approach (which should not be a downside in my use case) is that comments are stripped.

I also left some commented print statements, in case someone would like to explore the various steps.